# Line integral for $y=1/x$

Tags: integration

I'm interested in calculating the line integral for $y=1/x$. I would be grateful if somebody could show me how this is done.

In case you were wondering I'm a bit too old for homework !!!  and maybe too old to be able to do this sort of calculus.

Comment: What are you integrating?

Comment: Where are you integrating y=1/x? the indefinite integral is log x + C

Comment: line integral and its not easy

Comment: ok heres the question rephrased to make it easier to see why im interested in the LINE INTEGRAL

Comment: ok heres the question rephrased to make it easier to see why im interested in the LINE INTEGRAL  suppose x*y=n as in the factorisation of a number ... then using parameterisation running the integral from say root(n) , root (n) [the square root of the number about which the line integral is symetric ] to 1,n   then the parametric equation  gives [root(n)  + ( 1 - root (n) t] , [root (n) + (n- root(n) t]  call them A and B The integral then becomes I { (root [ (1- root(n))^2 + (n+root(n) ^2] / (A*B)     hope its clearer now what im trying to do

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you want to calculate the length of the line $1/x$ over some interval. The line element is $\sqrt{dy^2+dx^2}$, so the length of the line is $\int \sqrt{(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+1} dx=\int \sqrt{1/x^4+1} dx$ (assuming you are staying away from $x=0$). Wolfram alpha will integrate this for you but it looks real ugly.

Comment: wolfram would not calculate 1/x as a line integral   it can be done i would imagine using parameterisation

Comment: it did indeed calculate it and it was very messy ...it also included two symbols i dont understand xF and xE   any idea what these might be ????  i cant get the result out of the gif its presented in so cant post it here sadly. It should be reflexive about root x,  after all its basically the multiplication of two numbers represented by x and y  thanks btw

Comment: Its x * F not xF. F is an elliptic integral of the first kind and E elliptic integral of second kind. There should be a link to these on the same page Wolfram gave the answer on.

Comment: Also Wolfram gives a simplified result further down the page assuming x>0.

Comment: yes it does in fact say so on the page though im not at all convinced from the graphical  output that the integral is correct As i said effectively it is x*y = say a number   and the graph doesnt give any degree of confidence knowing this simple fact .. when i asked this question i knew it looked simple but wasnt .. i had  a stab at using parameterisation but didnt get a sensible answer and i dont think the above gives it   Im very tempted to write a program to effectively integrate the line by generating a seris of points and adding the lengths

Comment: I noticed the graph, why is it negative for x>0? I guess because of the constant term which will go away when the limits are put in.